Oracle PL/SQL Types not getting used in procedure
Given below is the code. If I try to use the TYPES outside the procedure it errors out.
When I try to declare the same types inside the proc it works fine. What is the issue here?
drop type t_tf_order_tbl;
drop type t_tf_order_row;

create or replace TYPE t_tf_order_row as OBJECT
(order_id number,
line_qty number,
total_value number);

create or replace TYPE t_tf_order_tbl as TABLE OF t_tf_order_row;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_refcur_bulk_collect(p_ref_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
    v_tbl t_tf_order_tbl := t_tf_order_tbl();
BEGIN

    FETCH p_ref_cursor                    -- run-time error happens here
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_tbl;  
    
    FOR i IN v_tbl.FIRST .. v_tbl.LAST
    LOOP        
        dbms_output.put_line(v_tbl(i).order_id||', '||v_tbl(i).line_qty||', '||v_tbl(i).total_value);
    END LOOP;    
END;
/

Error starting at line : 39 in command -
BEGIN test_refcur_bulk_collect(fn_srf_get_order_rows(100)); END;
Error report -
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TEST_REFCUR_BULK_COLLECT", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
06504. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"

Now if use the TYPES inside the procedure I don't get an error. I am trying to understand what is happening here?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_refcur_bulk_collect(p_ref_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS

TYPE t_tf_order_row is record
(order_id number,
line_qty number,
total_value number);

TYPE t_tf_order_tbl is TABLE OF t_tf_order_row;    **--USING THE SAME TYPES INSIDE THE PROC WORKS FINE**

    v_tbl t_tf_order_tbl := t_tf_order_tbl();
BEGIN

    FETCH p_ref_cursor                     --works fine
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_tbl;  
    
    FOR i IN v_tbl.FIRST .. v_tbl.LAST
    LOOP        
        dbms_output.put_line(v_tbl(i).order_id||', '||v_tbl(i).line_qty||', '||v_tbl(i).total_value);
    END LOOP;    
END;
/

Procedure TEST_REFCUR_BULK_COLLECT compiled

exec test_refcur_bulk_collect(fn_srf_get_order_rows(100));
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

100, 10, 942.97
100, 9, 177.39


If you do:
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  OPEN v_cur FOR
    SELECT 1 as order_id, 2 AS line_qty, 3 AS total_value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

  test_refcur_bulk_collect(v_cur);

  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
/

then you get the exception:
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_JPCILGNDMQIKAQEVREAQ.TEST_REFCUR_BULK_COLLECT", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 10

However, if you pass in a cursor containing the objects in a single column (and not the object's attributes as three columns) then your code works:
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  OPEN v_cur FOR
    SELECT t_tf_order_row(1, 2, 3) AS order_row FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT t_tf_order_row(4, 5, 6) FROM DUAL;

  test_refcur_bulk_collect(v_cur);

  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
/  

Outputs:
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6


Now if use the TYPES inside the procedure I don't get an error.

That is because the PL/SQL type is a RECORD and the SQL type is an OBJECT and they are different types and how they are handled is slightly different. If you want to use a table of objects then you can pass a cursor of objects and the code will work.
fiddle
